# Struts 2 Action not Consuming json data

Tags: json, web-services, struts2

I have configured and coded a simple web service call to a Struts 2 Action.  I am not getting the data from the call but it is returning JSON properly.  I am using Postman to make the call.

```
public class WSLaborJONAction
{
    // this property is not getting populated on the call
    private String test;

    public String execute() throws Exception
    {
         ...some code
         return "success";
    }

    public String getTest()
    {
            return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test)
    {
        this.test = test;
    }
}
```

```
<package name="webservices" namespace="/" extends="json-default">
    <result-types>
        <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult" />
    </result-types>
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor" />
    </interceptors>

    <!-- LABOR JON -->  
    <action name="WSLaborJON" class="mil.ndms.taa.af.webservices.labor.WSLaborJONAction">
        <result name="success" type="json" />
    </action>       

</package>
```

```
GET /taa/WSLaborJON
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.13.0
Accept: '*/*'
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 111a91a2-919f-4469-a96c-c5b666c9ebec
Host: localhost:8080
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 30
Connection: keep-alive
{
    "test":"MyInputTest"
}

HTTP/1.1 200
status: 200
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 23
Date: Tue, 11 Jun 2019 18:02:13 GMT
{"test":"MyOutputTest"}
```

My String test is always null.  I need to consume it in the Action from the JSON call.  Any ideas of what I am missing?

Comment: I don't understand the question; you say it's returning the JSON correctly but the string is null. You show a working request/response. What isn't working? Remove unrelated garbage (and incorrect at that) code from the code snippet.

Comment: @DaveNewton My String test is not populated when the WS is called.  What unrelated garbage?  Are you referring to the Postman results that show the request and response.  It shows that I am making a request with json data and getting a response with json data.  The response is OK but my test var in the Action class  is not populated with the input json data

Comment: I still don't understand. You show that the postman call is correct, but there's no way to know what's happening in the action (the code you had previously had a bogus string compare, btw).

Comment: Typically you want to POST man request but you did GET which is completely different thing. In struts2 interceptors are always override to each other when configured to the action.